# .json data shows in webpack server, but not production build

Tags: javascript, html, json, webpack, vue.js

When I load my site using `npm run dev` for development, there is no issue. However, when I build my site using `npm run prod` for a production build, data from my .json does not appear on the webpage, nor does it show in my outputted dist folder.

I am using Webpack 4. I thought the code below was changing the paths of my references to the .json files, and outputting the .json files to my dist/assets folder, similar to the .png, .woff etc. files. Unfortunately, it does not. (not sure why).

```
  module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
      filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
    module: {
      rules: [
        ...
        {
           test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|eot|ttf|woff|woff2|json)$/,
           loader: 'file-loader',
           options: {
             name: '[name].[ext]',
             outputPath: './assets'
           }
        },
        ...
      ]
   },
   ...
```

In the code below, I use XMLHttpRequest() to get the content of two.json files. The two .json files I am referencing load in the development server, but do not load when I run the production build. The code below is inside a `.vue` component called `PeriodicTable.vue` (I don't think Vue is the problem here).

```
mounted: function() {
       ...
       var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
       var self = this;
       var url = "/src/assets/data/main.json";
       xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
       xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
         if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
           self.elements = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText).elements;
         }
       }
       xmlhttp.send();

       var xmlhttp2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
       var self = this;
       var url2 = "/src/assets/data/groupPeriodLabels.json";
       xmlhttp2.open("GET", url2, true);
       xmlhttp2.onreadystatechange = function() {
         if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
           self.periodLabels = JSON.parse(xmlhttp2.responseText).periodLabels;
           self.groupLabels = JSON.parse(xmlhttp2.responseText).groupLabels;
         }
       }
       xmlhttp2.send();
     }
     ...
```

You can view my file directory in the photograph below, or see all code at the [repository](https://github.com/EanKeen/periodic-table/tree/a63b6221ca8df8494bc2d042f016851672d82c59) in which this code is hosted at.

[image: File Directory]

The XMLHttpRequest() file does not seem to find the right path to the .json files in the production build. Does it have something to do with `import`, `require`, or `url()`? Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: I have an index.js, which includes the following:

```
// index.js
import './css/main.scss';
import 'material-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css';


// VueJS
import Vue from 'vue';
window.Vue = Vue;

// VueSax (UI elements for Vue)
import Vuesax from 'vuesax'
import 'vuesax/dist/vuesax.css' // Gather VueSax styles
Vue.use(Vuesax, {
  theme: {
    colors: {
    }
  }
})

// Feather Icons (Icon library for Vue)
import VueFeatherIcon from 'vue-feather-icon';
Vue.use(VueFeatherIcon);

import Navigation from './components/Navigation.vue';
import PeriodicTable from './components/PeriodicTable.vue';
import Footer from './components/Footer.vue';

new Vue({
  render: k => k(Navigation)
}).$mount('#navigation-el')

new Vue({
   render: h => h(PeriodicTable)
 }).$mount('#grid-el')

new Vue({
  render: m => m(Footer)
}).$mount('#footer-el')
```

Comment: What's in your `config/index.js`?

Comment: @dziraf It is now edited in the question. My apologizes for not originally including it.

Comment: nah, not this one - give the one from `config` folder which contains build paths

Comment: @dziraf hmm. I don't have a config folder - the only index.js file I have is the one I posted in the question. I thought my webpack.common.js / webpack.prod.js contained the necessary build paths, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have some misconceptions on what `file-loader` does. `file-loader` certainly does copy files to your dist directory, but it only copies files over *if they're loaded by the code*. Currently, webpack doesn't know that the file exists. If you did a `require('./some.json')` (or import), that would trigger the file loader and substitute the URL. In the code that does the fetch, replace:

```
var url = "/src/assets/data/main.json";
```

...with:

```
var url = require('../assets/data/main.json');
```

...and that will do the proper rewriting/output.

**Update**:

You also need an additional step. Webpack 4 by default includes JSON file contents in your JS bundle, which you don't want since you're wanting to *download* it instead. To work around, I added a rule to your `webpack.common.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  // ...
  module: {
    rules: [
      // ...Right before your file-loader rule
      // Bypass automatic `.json` file processing for webpack
      {
        type: 'javascript/auto',
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[ext]',
          outputPath: './assets'
        }
      },
      // Second file loader. note the removal of the `json` pattern
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[ext]',
          outputPath: './assets'
        }
      }
    ],
    // ...
  }
  // ...
};
```

...and now requiring the `.json` files triggers `file-loader`.

Comment: Tested this out, but something else is going wrong when webpack is processing the JSON files. Investigating...

Comment: I see now! It makes sense that I have to do this since I want to download the files rather than include it in the JS bundle. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Gah, I jumped the gun... the JSON file is copied over, but it's not JSON, but instead some JS content.

Comment: Ah, also have to make sure to remove the `json` from the pattern of the second `file-loader`.

Comment: hmm. I think I did that automatically, since it works for me - I see the edit now, thanks!